# Equations with nodes 72 degrees apart

Tags: geometry, functions, 3d

I am interested the nodal ($z=0$) behavior of the following functions for a small research project:

$$z=x(x^2-3y^2)$$
$$z=y(3x^2-y^2)$$

When graphed, there are nodes 60° ($n=6$) apart from each other. I am interested in finding analogous equations where there are nodes 72° ($n=5$) apart from each other, where (degrees=$360/n$).

Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: with $w = x + i y$  where $i^2 = -1, $  let $z$  be the real part of $w^5.$  The other main choice is the imaginary part of $w^5$